# Java, synchronize db write across the whole system

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Is it possible to create a class and use it to synchronized some operations (e.g.) DB write in order to just do that operation not simultaneously?

```
public class Sync {
}

public class A {
    public void doStuff() {
        [...]       
        synchronized(Sync.class){
            object1.write();
        }
    }   
}

public class B {        
    public void doStuff(){
        [...]
        synchronized(Sync.class){
            object2.write();
        }
    }   
}


public class C {
    public void doStuff(){
        [...]
        synchronized(Sync.class){
            object3.write();
        }
    }   
}
```

In this way different `.write()` action should not run simultaneously.
Isn't it?